# How to disable the announcement banner?

Tags: support, top-bar

Lately when visiting sites on the Stack Exchange network, I have seen this announcement banner popping up, right underneath the top bar.  Here is a screenshot of today's announcement banner:

[image: announcement banner]

Now I absolutely don't care what some guy I've never heard of has to say about Git or any other thing on their pointless podcast.  To stop getting annoyed by this rubbish I'd just like to hide this announcement banner altogether but I can't find an appropriate option in the settings.

How do I disable the announcement banner **permanently**?

Comment: Since this is network wide, wouldn't it be better to post this on global meta?

Comment: Related: [Dismiss the “Meet The Overflow” and Podcast Episode banners network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334137/168244)

Comment: The banner has disappeared since this morning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because for now the announcement banner is gone.

Comment: @HenriMenke Very kind there is again the bar of the advice: **Podcast: We chat with Major League Hacking about all-nighters, cup stacking, and therapy dogs. Listen now.**

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question because the stupid announcement banner is back again.

Comment: This is a quantum mechanical effect. The banner is only there if someone observes it. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It's back again with another installment of their irrelevant garbage podcast.

Comment: You made the mistake of observing it. ;-) More seriously, this is a company whose actions are due to commercial considerations. Even if *you* put in all these amazing efforts to keep pgf alive and even improve it (which I **really** appreciate a lot), and do all this for free, there are others who do not think in this way.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't see how PGF is relevant here. I just want an option to permanently disable this stupid banner, that costs precious screen real estate.  Also the podcast advertisement is already in the sidebar, so I don't see why they have to waste space on duplicate information.

Comment: Why is this stupid announcement banner reappearing all the time.  I don't give a shit about your company.  I'm ad-blocking this garbage now.

Answer (score 8):

In line with their [extremely poor attitude towards the volunteers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Moderator_removal), helping out on this site, the Stack Exchange team has not even denied this request, but chose to simply ignore it.

Therefore I decided to just ad-block the banner using uBlock origin (together with all other ads on this site).  The custom blocking rules for all Stack Exchange sites and Stack Overflow are

```
stackexchange.com###announcement-banner
stackoverflow.com###announcement-banner
```

Add these through the uBlock origin Dashboard under the tab “My filters”